# indexoutofbound error when shifting 2D array elements java

Tags: java, arrays, loops

```
    public static int[][] shift(final int[][] original, final int amount) {

    int[][] shifted = new int[original.length][original[0].length];


    for (int col = 0; col < original.length; col++) {
        for (int row = 0; row < original[col].length; row++) {
            shifted[col][row] = FILL_VALUE;
        }

    for (int cols = 0; cols < original.length + amount; cols++) {
        for (int rows = 0; rows < original[cols].length; rows++) {
            if (cols - amount < original.length) {
                shifted[cols][rows] = original[cols - amount][rows];
            }
        }
   }
   }
    return shifted;
}
```

Hi, 
I am trying to write a method that will shift the elements in my 2-D array to the left by some arbitrary amount. I don't want to loop the values back around, but instead fill the empty arrays with some fill_value which is already predefined. And if the shift amount is more than the orignial length, I would just return an image with only fill_value. However, this function is throwing an arrayindexoutofbound Error. But I can't think of how I should change my for loop to fix the error. Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because in your second outer for loop, the condition is cols < length + amount, so it will continue past the edge of the array if amount > 0. You could step through your code with a debugger and see exactly where it's going out of bounds.

Comment: Would this be what you mean by to check where it's going out of bounds..this is the exact error message "Something went wrong: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -16"  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring because of following line:

shifted[cols][rows] = original[cols - amount][rows];

When cols=0, rows=0, amount=2 (say), it is trying to access original[-2][0] which does not exist.

Instead you may use following:

```
public class overflow1 {

    static int a[][] = {{1,2,3,4,5,6},{2,3,4,5,6,7},{3,4,5,6,7,8}, {4,5,6,7,8,9}, {5,6,7,8,9,10}, {6,7,8,9,10,11}};
    static int b[][] ;

    static int FILL_VALUE =0;

    public static int[][] shift(final int[][] original, final int amount) {

    int[][] shifted = new int[original.length][original[0].length];


    for (int col = 0; col < original.length; col++) {
        for (int row = 0; row < original[col].length; row++) {
            shifted[col][row] = FILL_VALUE;
        }

     for (int cols = 0; cols < original.length ; cols++) {
        for (int rows = 0; rows < original[cols].length; rows++) {
            if (cols - amount >=0) {
                shifted[cols][rows] = original[cols - amount][rows];
            }
        }
   }
   }
    return shifted;
  }

  public static void main(String[] arggs) {

    b=shift(a,2);

      System.out.println("Original array:");
      for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
          for (int j=0; j<a[i].length; j++){
              System.out.print(a[i][j]+ ":");
          }
          System.out.println();
      }

    System.out.println("After shift by 2 array:");
    for(int i=0; i<b.length; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<b[i].length; j++){
            System.out.print(b[i][j]+ ":");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the output for the sample:

Original array:

1:2:3:4:5:6:

2:3:4:5:6:7:

3:4:5:6:7:8:

4:5:6:7:8:9:

5:6:7:8:9:10:

6:7:8:9:10:11:

After shift by 2, array:

0:0:0:0:0:0:

0:0:0:0:0:0:

1:2:3:4:5:6:

2:3:4:5:6:7:

3:4:5:6:7:8:

4:5:6:7:8:9: